# How to parallelize a bash for loop and use the iteration variable for file IO

Tags: bash, parallelism

I have a bash script that more or less looks like this:

```
N=32
for i in $(seq -f "%06g" 0 ${LAST_NUM}) # LAST_NUM is an env variable
do
  ((j=j%N)); ((j++==0)) && wait # Wait for all processes in batch to finish
  python foo1.py $i &
  python foo2.py "foo1_output${i}.file_extension" &
  python foo3.py "foo2_output${i}.file_extension" &
done
```

When I check the output, I get `FileNotFound` errors for the intermediate files `foo1_output${i}.file_extension`. Although I haven't confirmed this, I suspect that the state of `i` may not be attached to the process that spawned in that loop. I want one process to be responsible for one iteration of the loop, not merely the first command in the loop. Is my code above in error, and if so, what would be the correct way to approach this?

Comment: I think you want something like `(python foo1.py $i; python foo2.py "foo1_output${i}.file_extension"; python foo3.py "foo2_output${i}.file_extension") &` - send a subshell to the background that runs all three commands in sequence

Comment: @muru So you're saying if I encapsulate all of my commands in `()` (which I assume you can do across lines) and background that one total process, then the state for one process will be constant until its iteration of the loop is complete?

Comment: It's not really about "state". The problem appears to be that the "foo1_output..." file does not exist until foo1.py completes. Therefore, delay execution of foo2.py until foo1.py exits.

Comment: And yes, the contents of `(...)` is a _script_, so newlines are perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0):

You do not ask for a solution based on GNU Parallel, but GNU Parallel is specifically built for exactly these kind of tasks, so maybe it is relevant.

```
doit() {
  i="$1"
  python foo1.py $i
  python foo2.py "foo1_output${i}.file_extension"
  python foo3.py "foo2_output${i}.file_extension"
}
export -f doit

# This will run one job per CPU thread (e.g. 32 if your server has 32 CPU thread)
seq -f "%06g" 0 ${LAST_NUM} | parallel doit

# If you really want to force 32 in parallel:
N=32
seq -f "%06g" 0 ${LAST_NUM} | parallel -j$N doit
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons you should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Read the book: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel